# Limit app install on devices having A8 Processor or later (iPhone 6 and later)

Tags: ios, iphone, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I have an app primarily based on Metal Performance Shaders framework. But this framework isn't supported on iPhone5S since it uses processor A7. As a result, the app would be meaningless if it ran on 5s.

So I want to restrict App Store availability in such a way that app is available only for devices iPhone 6 and above, i.e Processor A8 or later.

I found a way to restrict devices iPhone 5 and below using the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in Info.plist but couldn't find any key where I could differentiate iPhone 5s with other latest devices.

Is there any way for the same?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's currently no way to do this. Unfortunately, iPad mini 2 and iPad mini 3 also fall into this category (supporting Metal but not MPS). I recommend [filing a Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) with this enhancement request.

Comment: @warrenm filed at rdar://31805344 Btw, even the iPad Air 1 doesn't support MPS. So many unsupported devices yet no proper way to differentiate them!